# Spring boot app not launching in Tomcat openshift

Tags: java, spring, deployment, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot webapp in a Tomcat 8 image on an Openshift instance, but I'm presented with the following error after a few seconds:

```
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext:546 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:481 - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG o.h.i.SessionFactoryImpl:1339 - HHH000031: Closing
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG o.h.s.i.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl:406 - Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG o.h.b.r.i.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl:308 - Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG o.h.j.i.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry:108 - Remove: name=default
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter:327 - Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'iaasservicesportalDataSource'
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS INFO  c.j.b.BoneCP:159 - Shutting down connection pool...
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG c.j.b.PoolWatchThread:96 - Terminating pool watch thread
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG c.j.b.PoolWatchThread:96 - Terminating pool watch thread
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG c.j.b.PoolWatchThread:96 - Terminating pool watch thread
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS INFO  c.j.b.BoneCP:188 - Connection pool has been shutdown.
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG c.j.b.BoneCPDataSource:144 - Connection pool has been shut down
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter:249 - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'characterEncodingFilter'
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter:249 - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'httpPutFormContentFilter'
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter:249 - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter:249 - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'requestContextFilter'
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter:249 - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor'
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication:827 - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties$Tomcat.customizeRemoteIpValve(ServerProperties.java:794)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties$Tomcat.customizeTomcat(ServerProperties.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties.customize(ServerProperties.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
2016-08-25 09:22:08 IAAS INFO  o.s.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener:57 - Application failed to start with classpath: (...)

2016-08-25 09:22:08,234 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase- ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties$Tomcat.customizeRemoteIpValve(ServerProperties.java:794)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties$Tomcat.customizeTomcat(ServerProperties.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties.customize(ServerProperties.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 28 more
2016-08-25 09:22:08,241 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Error deploying web application archive /deployments/ROOT.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-08-25 09:22:08,245 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deployment of web application archive /deployments/ROOT.war has finished in 38,854 ms
2016-08-25 09:22:08,271 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol- Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
2016-08-25 09:22:08,327 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina- Server startup in 39140 ms
```

This runs fine in a standalone Tomcat8 server installed on both my local PC and a remote server, though not on this Tomcat template at our corporate Openshift

Comment: Have you had any luck with the deployment

Comment: Yes, forgot to update this. IIRC it was a problem with the pom.xml dependencies not being correct. I'll post my pom file for you to see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again changing some properties in the pom.xml file and it worked! Pay attention to the Tomcat-related ones because they are probably what needed change Here's my pom if it helps (Not all dependencies are required obviously):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: I posted my question here, please take a look and let me know if there is any issue in my code `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392939/error-starting-spring-boot-openshift-application-unable-to-start-embedded-tomca`

Comment: @fernandopcg I have exactly the same issue. Tried applying a similar set of dependencies but it still hangs at the same place (on the Catalina Server Startup...). Any chance you could share the rest of your pom? Do you recall if you made any other changes?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I had to change from the spring boot parent pattern to the spring boot BOM pattern. Additionally I still had the problem until I removed the "spring-boot-maven-plugin." That was making the war executable. Example Pom that has the spring boot bom, and no parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>org.sample</groupId>
   <artifactId>winner</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>winner</name>

   <properties>
      <spring.boot.version>2.2.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
      <tomcat.version>8.5.2</tomcat.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <!-- Spring Boot BOM -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Servlet -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
         <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

</project>
```