# Error starting spring boot openshift application: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, openshift

I have used this [link](https://github.com/kolorobot/openshift-diy-spring-boot-sample) to create a DIY app with tomcat 8 & springboot. I modified the code from the above link to make it access mongodb instead of postgres. I have been banging my head to trying figuring out to start the sample application. Can anyone help me with this error.

**.openshift/action_hooks/deploy**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/m2/repository ]
then
    mkdir -p $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/m2/repository
fi

if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/logs ]
then
    mkdir -p $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/logs
fi

if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven-3.3.9 ]
then
    wget -P $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz
    tar xvf $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven*.tar.gz --directory $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
    rm -f $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven*.tar.gz
fi


export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
export M2=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms384m -Xmx412m"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR


$M2/mvn --version
$M2/mvn -s settings.xml clean install
```

**start**

```
#!/bin/bash

source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH

set -x

export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
nohup java -Xms384m -Xmx412m -jar target/*.jar --server.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT} --server.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP} --spring.profiles.active=openshift &
```

**stop**

```
#!/bin/bash

source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH

PID=$(ps -ef | grep java.*\.jar | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }')

if [ -z "$PID" ]
then
    client_result "Application is already stopped"
else
    kill $PID
fi
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.9</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application-openshift.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mongodb://${OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}
spring.datasource.username = ${OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password = ${OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD}

logging.file = ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/logs/app.log
logging.level. = INFOgi
```

**Error in the openshift console**

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at demo.Application.main(Application.java:10) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]        
remote:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]        
remote:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
remote:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]        
remote:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:104) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:61) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]        
remote: Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:457) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:168) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]        
remote:     ... 16 common frames omitted        
remote: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistentEntities' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities]: Factory method 'persistentEntities' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "openshift" are currently active).; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistentEntities' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities]: Factory method 'persistentEntities' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "openshift" are currently active).
```

**UPDATE**

I updated the springboot version to 1.4.1.RELEASE and now the exception is different. Its complaining about the Embedded Container

```
    remote:  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)
remote: 
remote: 2016-11-03 08:54:00.024  INFO 93239 --- [           main] demo.Application                         : Starting Application v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on ex-std-node853.prod.rhcloud.com with PID 93239 (/var/lib/openshift/581a74472d5271129a0000a6/app-root/runtime/repo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by 581a74472d5271129a0000a6 in /var/lib/openshift/581a74472d5271129a0000a6/app-root/runtime/repo)        
remote: 2016-11-03 08:54:00.025  INFO 93239 --- [           main] demo.Application                         : The following profiles are active: openshift        
remote: 2016-11-03 08:54:00.469  INFO 93239 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@15380c2: startup date [Thu Nov 03 08:54:00 EDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy        
remote: 2016-11-03 08:54:12.437  INFO 93239 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'managementServletContext' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=managementServletContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]]        
remote: 2016-11-03 08:54:13.579  INFO 93239 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!        
remote: 2016-11-03 08:54:14.202  INFO 93239 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface demo.repository.CustomerRepository.        
remote: 2016-11-03 08:54:15.764  INFO 93239 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!        
remote: 2016-11-03 08:54:19.720  INFO 93239 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee91494e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)        
remote: 2016-11-03 08:54:23.293  WARN 93239 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/SessionIdGenerator        
remote: 2016-11-03 08:54:23.337 ERROR 93239 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed        
remote: 
remote: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/SessionIdGenerator        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]        
remote:     at demo.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]        
remote:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]        
remote:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]        
remote:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]        
remote:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]        
remote: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/SessionIdGenerator        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:190) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:176) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]        
remote:     ... 16 common frames omitted        
remote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.SessionIdGenerator        
remote:     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]        
remote:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]        
remote:     at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:89) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]        
remote:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]        
remote:     ... 20 common frames omitted        
remote: 
remote: -------------------------
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251169/spring-boot-application-wont-start-in-openshift

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "openshift" are currently active).

You are attempting to use a database but you haven't provided any relevant information to Spring Boot to connect to it. Spring Boot 1.3.x does not support Mongo 3.x, you [need to upgrade to Spring Boot 1.4 first](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#mongodb-3)

Comment: Sure, I will try that and post and update, but Openshift has MongoDB 2.4.

Comment: I updated to Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE, I see a shorter error log. Please check the update